# How to move everything but the last files?

Tags: files, mv, file-management

How can I move everything but the last `n` files, from `dir1` to `dir2`?.

I currently do this, setting the time as an approximate for `n`, in my case `n=2` each 10 minutes.

```
find /dir1/ -name '*.txt*' -mmin +10 -type f -exec mv "{}" /dir2/ \;
```

A similar command, could work, but i am not certain, could somebody confirm how should adapt this?

```
ls -1tr | head -n -2 | xargs -d '\n' mv -f --
```

Comment: And I don't think a new answer is needed to replace `rm` by `mv` or changing on how many time-sorted files the action should be performed. (-:

Comment: What do you mean by filled? Maybe you should use -size instead of -mmin ?

Comment: Do you mean that files such as `20170713111152.txt` and `20170713111152.txt_aux` are created and appended to for 10 minutes until new ones, such as `20170713112152.txt` are created?

Comment: Take a solution, try to adapt it to your needs and come back with it if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
mv dir1/**/*.txt*(D.om[3,-1]) dir2/
```

Would move the regular files in `dir1` except for the 2 most recently modified ones to `dir2`.

- `**/`: any level of sub-directory.
- `D`: include hidden files and descend into hidden dirs.
- `.`: only regular files (no symlink, directory...), equivalent for `find`'s `-type f`.
- `om`: sort by modification time (most recent first like with `ls -t`).
- `[3,-1]`: only from 3rd to last

(you can issue a `zmodload zsh/files` to get a builtin `mv` or use `zargs` if you run into a *arg list too big* issue).

POSIXly, that simply can't be done without making some assumptions on the names of the files, the number of files and the length of their paths.

GNUly (with recent versions of GNU tools for `-z`), you could do:

```
find dir1 -name '*.txt*' -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
  sort -rnz | tail -zn +3 | cut -zf2- | xargs -r0 mv -t dir2
```

While GNU `sort` and `xargs` have had `-z`/`-0` options for decades, the addition of `-z` for `cut` and `tail` is fairly recent. If you have older versions of those, you can always do:

```
find dir1 -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' | sort -rnz |
  tr '\n\0' '\0\n' |
  tail -n +3 | cut -f2- |
  tr '\n\0' '\0\n' | xargs -r0 mv -t dir2
```

Note that while those solutions look for files recursively in `dir1` (including in subdirectories), they won't recreate the same directory structure in `dir2`. That means that for instance if there were both a `dir1/file.txt` and `dir1/subdir/file.txt`, they would both end up being moved to `dir2/file.txt`, one overwriting the other.

Answer (score 2):

Since the datestamped files will be gathered together in order with shell globs (e.g. `*.txt`), you could use arrays (such as in bash):

```
n=2 ## how many of each you want to keep
txtfiles=(*.txt)
auxfiles=(*.txt_aux)
totaltxt=${#txtfiles[@]}
totalaux=${#auxfiles[@]}
movetxt=$((totaltxt-n))
moveaux=$((totalaux-n))
echo mv "${txtfiles[@]:0:movetxt}" /dir/aux2/
echo mv "${auxfiles[@]:0:moveaux}" /dir/aux2/
```

Remove the last two `echo` pieces when it looks like it's doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way of doing this:

```
mv `ls -tr sourcedir | head -n -2` destdir
```

Note: This assumes you know there are more than two files in the directory. If you're not sure, you can count them with `ls | wc -l`